# How to open a local html file using NavigationWindow when path contains URL fragment?

Tags: c#, wpf, anchor, navigationwindow

I am using [NavigationWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to display html files, it worked fine until path does not contain any # or illegal characters.

I just wanted to know is there a way to open html file when the path contains URL fragment, for example: an anchor # like below..

```
"c:\MyFile.Html#tips"
```

Currently i am getting the following exception...

```
Could not find file 'c:\MyFile.Html#tips'
System.Net.WebException was unhandled 

  HResult=-2146233079
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the creation of the URI, it seems there is some bug with the URI class.

The URI generated by the following are different,

```
var filePath = @"c:\MyFile.Html#tips";   
var uri = new Uri(filePath);
var uri2 = new Uri("file://" + filePath);
```

Fragment part of the `uri` is empty, but `uri2` has correct fragment part as "#tips".

The same kind of problem is with the query even after creating URI as `uri2`, the reported bug for query 
string can be found here, [Why doesn't System.Uri recognize query parameter for local file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757585/why-doesnt-system-uri-recognize-query-parameter-for-local-file-path) and [Uri class does not parse filesystem URL with query string](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/594562/uri-class-does-not-parse-filesystem-url-with-query-string)